# How can I let other people access my folders without using Google Drive, Dropbox and the like?

Tags: shared-folders, sharing

## Background

I don’t want Google, Dropbox and the likes to hold all my data. Ideally, I imagine a working environment in which I can keep all my data locally, and with a single switch, make a folder publicly accessible.

Yes, I can put this folder into my Dropbox or Google Drive folder and have it accessible to the public. But I don’t want to move folders. I want them to be where I want to put them within my “Home” folder. And I want people to stream the folder directly from my computer if I am online and connected. Only if I am not, then a caching server should be used to make the folder accessible to the person requesting it (e.g. through a link I shared) while I am offline.

## Mockup

[image: Mockup]

Comment: I think you can create symlinks to point to folders outside the Dropbox folder and Dropbox will resolve these symlinks and sync what they point to.

Comment: I would prefer not to rely on Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: Then consider something like Syncthing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's anything that does this out of the box.

In typically annoying stackexchange fashion I'll ask if you're sure you want changes to files to show up immediately rather than after you've reviewed any changes. If not then I might suggest using a VCS like git, and maybe your own server, or (paid) github, or (probably free) bitbucket. You might also be interested in the owncloud project in general.

I don't know of any immediate solution for what you want to do, so can only really give you suggestions of how you set something up yourself with various components:

- You could run an ssh server somewhere, keep all your files remote and then using something like sshfs to make them accessible from your computer (this is problematic if you have big files or aren't connected to the internet), but has the benefit of being simple.
- If you don't have a static IP you should be aware of dynamic dns and some of the suppliers, you can use this to allow people to connect to your computer wherever it is. Alternatively this can be achieved by ssh'ing into a static server and using the -R option to forward connections back to your machine with a static IP.
- The fallback logic complicates things. If you want to be snazzy you could try using some sort of unionfs (like aufs) on a linux so that accesses fallback to your cache (e.g have a server, make it possible for it to ssh to your machine, use sshfs to to host your files on the server, also keep a cache on the server, use unionfs to join toe two together, allow third parties to ssh to this machine)
- An alternative method for doing the fallback (if you are happy with connections to drop when you switch off your computer) is to do some sort of connection forwarding with a fallback connection. So first they try to ssh to your machine, but if this machine is down then ssh to some other machine where you keep a cache. If you have a server then HAProxy might be suitable for this.
- It might also be worth looking into something like gfs (a distributed filesystem) but this might be overkill

I should also add the default caveat that if you make services on your computer accessible to the outside world then you have to make sure they are secure, whereas third party companies employ people to do this for you. Of course the people they employ could also look at your data and provide backdoors to the government, so it's a bit of a trade off.